# How to get a set of outputs of a command to use them one by one later

Tags: python, sage

This is what I am trying to achieve while using Sage worksheet interface.

Assume that I wrote a code and it gave, for example, for each i in a range of lists, list[0]. (First element of each list)
So I have multiple outputs.
Now I want to use these outputs, consider them as a list, and take iterative combinations of elements of it.
Can I do that, and how?

Comment: Are you using the Sage notebook or the Sage cloud interface?

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is easiest to make a new list out of this.

```
for list in list_of_lists:
    list[0]
```

could become (I'm making a minimal change to your code)

```
new_list = []
for ls in list_of_lists:
    new_list.append(ls[0])
```

and then `new_list` should have what you want.  (For more concise ways to do this, learn about Python list comprehensions.)

Comment: I am using Sage cloud interface.

Comment: You shouldn't use `list` as a variable name, as it shadows the built-in `list`.

Comment: True, that was a bit lazy (though in practice I have been able to avoid problems with it).  I'll edit that.  Edit: Actually, it was to avoid making big changes in the original code from the OP, but oh well.

Answer (score 1):

I did this for L a list of lists and `lf = len(L)` and it worked.

```
liste = [list(L[i])[0] for i in range (1,lf)]
for (f1,f2,f3) in Combinations(liste,3):
..
```